# apache2 not listening on port even though apache2ctl -S shows it should be

Tags: apache, nagios

I have an apache2 server running on a Raspberry Pi with Buster, version 10.  It forwards port 80 to port 443 for https connections.  Works great.
I am trying to add Nagios to this server.  I have installed it and (obviously incorrectly) configured it.  When I run:

```
jordan@megabyte:~ $ sudo apache2ctl -S
```

Here is my output:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
*:8080                 megabyte.mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nagios4.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

To me, it looks like Nagios should be listening on port 8080 (as planned) but when I do

```
jordan@megabyte:~ $ nc -l -p 8080
```

It does not error out, suggesting that nothing is listening on port 8080.  And:

```
jordan@megabyte:/etc/apache2 $ sudo netstat -nltp | grep 8080
```

returns nothing, confirming the first test (after killing the nc)
I have tried restarting apache and even rebooting.
I'd be glad to post any requested files, I just don't know which ones are relevant anymore.

Comment: How is your apache forwarding port 80 to 443 if there is no virtual host running on port 80?

Comment: Apparently that is now broken. When I do nc -l -p 80, there are no errors and I can no longer access it on port 80

Comment: Do your Apache error logs contain any useful errors?

Comment: none that I can see.  Wouldn't apache2ctl -S show some errors also?

Comment: No, `apache2ctl -S` do not show all the error, some of them are just in logs.

Comment: So there are no errors in the logs.  I just re-flashed my SD card and apparently I never had port 80 redirecting to port 443 (chrome browser does it automatically?)

Comment: I'm really stuck on this.  What files can I upload to help?  Here is my error.log during an apache restart:`[Sat Apr 25 19:45:39.175073 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17747] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 25 19:45:39.758087 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17768] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 25 19:45:39.758403 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17768] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: Some progress.  I added Listen directives in (different) places and now port 80 is forwarded and both ports are in use:
`root@megabyte:/home/jordan# nc -l -p 8080
nc: Address already in use
root@megabyte:/home/jordan# nc -l -p 80
nc: Address already in use`
BUT, I still cannot access the nagios pages

Answer (score 0):

So, the URL for nagios is:

```
http://hostname:8080/nagios4
```

I was missing the 4

also, I added Listen directives right before the VirtualHost directives:

```
listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

That got it working